# How to add two Signer using Custom Button Logic in Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi, salesforce-service-cloud

Below i have coded the Custom Button in Javascript to add two signer in Docusign Envelope.

```js
var RROS='1';
var CRL='Email~{!Case.Hidden_Merchant_Email__c};LastName~{!Merchant__c.Name};Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1;Email~{!Account.PersonEmail};LastName~{!Account.LastName};Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';

var CCRM='Signer 1~Merchant;Signer 2~Account Holder';

var CCTM='Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer';

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Case.Id}&CRL="+CRL+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM;
```

But here only signer is added in Docusign Envelope. I need to add two Signer in  Envelope. Can anyone please provide the correct script if i made a mistake in the given code?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send to more than one recipient. Even better, not all of the recipients need to be signers. Eg, you can send to some people to get a copy of the document after it's been signed, rather than sign. There are other options too, including Sign in person signers, etc.

Anyhow, multiple recipients are sent via the CRL query parameter, separated with commas. This documented on [page 67 of the Admin Guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-for-salesforce-administrator-guide)

Here's my version of your code (untested).

```
var RROS='1',
CRL='Email~{!Case.Hidden_Merchant_Email__c};' +
    'LastName~{!Merchant__c.Name};' +
    'Role~Signer 1;' +
    'RoutingOrder~1,' + // end of signer 1
    'Email~{!Account.PersonEmail};' + 
    'LastName~{!Account.LastName};' +
    'Role~Signer 2;' + 
    'RoutingOrder~2,' + // end of signer 2
    'LoadDefaultContacts~1',
CCRM='Signer 1~Merchant;Signer 2~Account Holder',
CCTM='Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer',
qparams = 'DSEID=0&' +
          'SourceID={!Case.Id}&' + 
          'CRL="' + CRL + '"&' +
          'RROS="' + RROS + '"&' +
          'CCRM="' + CCRM + '"&' +
          'CCTM="' + CCTM + '"';

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?" + qparams;
```